# iPhone SE running iOS 9.x won't recognize Bluetooth 5.0 devices

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect my iPhone SE to a MacBook Pro that has Bluetooth 5.0, that's supposed to be backwards compatible to Bluetooth 4.2 that the iPhone has.

I can see the iPhone in the device list on the MacBook's screen suggesting that it is able to discover the iPhone. However the MacBook won't appear in the device list on the iPhone.

I am able to tap connect to iPhone on the MacBook and I see a popup in the iPhone's screen saying that the MacBook wants to pair with the code 123456. Yet after accepting the pairing, it immediately disconnects.

I don't know where to start debugging.

Comment: It appears like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). May I ask the specific reason why you wish to pair your iPhone and MacBook over Bluetooth? Do you have reasons not to not upgrade to the current iOS which your iPhone supports?

Comment: The reason is outside of the scope of apple stackexchange. I'm developing an application for ios 9 platform and thus the device must keep this OS version.